# elementary OS won't accept login details

Tags: greeter

I recently started using elementary OS over Ubuntu, as a newbi32 the interface really appealed. However, in the last few days, I've been unable to login. I've tried amending my root password using a guide, using recovery mode, however it has had no effect. Every time I attempt to log in, the password will be accepted, the screen turns dark and then I'm popped back into the login page, is there anything I can do to change this?

Thank you in advance for any help you are able to give.

Comment: For some reason your session is crashing. Have you recently installed/changed any drivers or installed/changed/removed any other apps?